# Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found on spark-scala-s3 using build.sbt, failing at reading file on S3

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3, jar, sbt

Trying to read a file on S3 bucket from spark and scala program but it is failing at read step which reads the file from S3 with the below error.

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException Create breakpoint: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found.

But same code is working with sbt on linux machine with the below steps

project_dir# sbt clean
project_dir# sbt compile
project_dir# sbt run

If jar is created for the same code, that jar is not working when it is executed using spark-submit

project_dir# sbt package

Comment: Please share your build.sbt file. This is a very generic error message.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.